# Updating appsettings.json file during CI build pipeline temporarily

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, entity-framework-migrations, appsettings

I have a .NET Core app that is built in Azure DevOps CI pipeline. During the CI I also generate sql scripts from EF migrations using `dotnet ef migrations script` command which then are being run during CD pipeline. Everything was fine when i used to store the connection string in `appsettings.json` file. But that is not the case any more, now I am using User Secrets for local and Azure AppService Application settings for deployed version. That means CI pipeline will fail once it tries to run `dotnet` command as the connection string will be empty. I did my research to see if connection string dynamically can be added to [dotnet command](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/cli-commands-for-ef-core-migration.aspx#migrations-script) on the run but that is not an option (just yet, but looks like dev team has plans for it). I came up with idea of transforming the appsettings.json file during CI. Basically i store the connection string under variables and inject it to appsettings.json file by using [File Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops#json-variable-substitution) task. But the problem is that this task will update and save the file, which means during publish it will have the updated file. But what i want is to transform the file just temporarily so that i can run dotnet command without any problem and also not deploy the json file with connection string in it. Any idea how i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File Transform task only works with variables. Therefore I ended up using [Magic Chunk](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeyzwezdin.magic-chunks) task 2 times. One task to transform appsettings.json so that it will have connection string before generating sql script. The second task does the reverse - transforming appsettings.json again so that connection string will be empty string after migrations sql script generated.